# Creation form for models with polymorphism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model 'item', two models 'bar' and 'restaurant' and a model 'user'.

The relations between those models are:

- User has_many :bars and has_many :restaurants
- Item belongs_to :activity, polymorphic: true
- Bar has_many :items, as: :activity
- Restaurant has_many :items, as: :activity

How my _form view to create a new item should be like?
A user can create an item and assign it to a model that can be bar or restaurant, so i would like that user can choose in which activity the item should belongs to.
In my form i have something like <%= f.select :activity, @my_activities.collect { |a| [a.name, a.id] } %> but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For polymorphic associations you use a [`fields_for`](https://gorails.com/episodes/forum-nested-attributes-and-fields-for) block:

```
<%= form_for(@bar) do |f| %>
  Bar<br />
  <%= select :id, options_for_select(@bars.map {|i| [i.name, i.id]}, include_blank: true) %><br />
  New Item<br />
  <%= f.fields_for :items do |a| %>
    Kind: <%= a.select :kind, options_for_select(Item.kinds.keys.map.with_index {|k,i| [k, i]}) %><br /> <!-- # If you have an enum of kind for item -->
    Vendor: <%= a.select :vendor_id, options_for_select(current_user.vendors.map {|i| [i.name, i.id]}) %><br /> <!-- # If you have specific vendors per user -->
    Name: <%= a.text_field :name %><br />
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will go inside your `form_for` tag.  Use `fields_for` block to nest **any** polymorphic relation.

You would only use `select` for an attribute that exists when creating something **new**.  The example you've partly written out looks like you're simply selecting from existing items.  That would be a different answer if you're looking for that.  You've specifically asked about creating an item.  So you won't be using `select` for creating something by name, you will need a `text_field` to enter the new name.

You can ignore the two `select` fields for your solution.  They are there to demonstrate `select`.  I don't believe your answer needs a `select` field.

https://gorails.com/episodes/forum-nested-attributes-and-fields-for

---

On another note your naming scheme for Item may be confusing.  The standard naming would be more like.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :itemable, polymorphic: true
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, as: :itemable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, reject_if: proc { |att| att['name'].blank? }
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, as: :itemable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, reject_if: proc { |att| att['name'].blank? }
end
```

In this case you would use a `fields_for` on `:items`.  The polymorphic relationship name `activity` or `itemable` is not referred to in the `fields_for` field.  Rather it is the plural for `Item` so `:items`.

---

#### To answer:

> i have a page to add an item, where the user fill informations like
>   title, description, etc, and then chooses in which 'bar' or
>   'restaurant' he wants to publish it.

```
<%= form_for(@item) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :itemable_type, options_for_select([Bar.name, Restaurant.name]) %>
  <%= f.select :itemable_id, [1,2,3] %># COMPLICATION, NEED AJAX/JS TO GET AVAILABLE IDs
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

Well this is basically what you want to do.  But you would need to have an Ajax/JavaScript call to change the available options for `:itemable_id` to the list of either Bars or Restaurants mapped with [:name, :id].  You could just use a text field to input the number of the ID of the Bar/Restaurant but this is not a user friendly experience.

If I was proficient in JavaScript I could give you a way to do this.  One way would be to have duplicate `:itemable_id` fields and have javascript disable/remove whichever the select field it isn't using.

#### Alternative solution 1:

You could make a page for each type `new_bar_item.html.erb` and `new_restaurant_item.html.erb` and each of those you would simply put a `hidden_field` for `itemable_type` to be either `Bar.name` or `Restaurant.name` respectively.   And then you would already know which collection to give to your `select` field.  Map the collections for the select field to your :name, :id.  This removes all the complication for doing this.

#### A workable solution 2:

A good way I can recommend to do it without JavaScript is to have both Bars and Restaurants listed.

```
<%= form_tag(@item) do |f| %>
  Choose either Bar or Restaurant.<br />
  Bar: <%= select_tag 'item[bar_id]', options_for_select(@bars.map {|i| [i.name, i.id]}, include_blank: true) %><br />
  Restaurant: <%= select_tag 'item[restaurant_id]', options_for_select(@restaurants.map {|i| [i.name, i.id]}, include_blank: true) %><br />
  Item name: <%= text_field_tag 'item[name]' %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your **ItemController** you will need to write a method to check which field isn't blank and set the polymorphic type with that.

```
before_action :set_poly_by_params, only: [:create, :update]

private
def set_poly_by_params
  if !params["item"]["bar_id"].empty? ^ !params["item"]["restaurant_id"].empty?
    if !params["item"]["bar_id"].empty?
      params["item"]["itemable_id"] = params["item"].delete("bar_id")
      params["item"]["itemable_type"] = Bar.name
    else
      params["item"]["itemable_id"] = params["item"].delete("restaurant_id")
      params["item"]["itemable_type"] = Restaurant.name
    end
  else
    raise "some error about incorrect selection"
  end
end
# NOTE: The above code will fail if the form doesn't submit both a bar_id field and a restaurant_id.  It expects both, empty or not.
```

#### Solution 3 (revised #2)

```
<%= form_tag(@item) do |f| %>
  Location: <%= select_tag 'item[venue]', options_for_select(
    @bars.map {|i| [i.name, "b"+i.id.to_s]} +
    @restaurants.map {|i| i.name, "r"+i.id.to_s]}
  ) %><br />
  Item name: <%= text_field_tag 'item[name]' %>
<% end %>
```

We've added a `b` before the ID for bar or `r` before the ID for restaurant.  Then we simply need to parse the params for it.

```
before_action :set_poly_by_params, only: [:create, :update]

private
def set_poly_by_params
  if params["item"]["venue"]["b"]
    params["item"]["itemable_type"] = Bar.name
  else
    params["item"]["itemable_type"] = Restaurant.name
  end
  params["item"]["itemable_id"] = params["item"].delete("venue")[1..-1]
end
```

This meets your requirement of one select field with both Bars and Restaurants in it.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I changed the naming scheme. I can get it working. I'm trying to explain it better: i have a page to add an item, where the user fill informations like title, description, etc, and then chooses in which 'bar' or 'restaurant' he wants to publish it.

Comment: Yes.  I had forgotten to mention you need to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :items` to each model that `has_many`.  That is the glue that allows the `fields_for` to work.

Comment: I see what your saying... give me a moment.

Comment: Personally I don't like solution2 because of multiple select. I'm trying to implement solution 1 that may be suits better and is better for user experience imho.

Comment: I'm trying to implement you solution3, but when i load the page, it gives me "undefined method `venue'" because there is no venue attribute in item model.

Comment: And anyway if a change :venue to :itemable for example, item saves with the value of itemable_type that is the name of the bar or restaurant, but it doesn't save the id so that doesn't work.

Comment: It shouldn't save `venue`.  That's why I have `.delete("venue")` in there to get rid of it.  Because leaving it in params would cause problems.  Deleting it from `params` both gives us the value we want and removes the problem of it trying to save.  Perhaps you need to add other actions to your `before_action`.  Or maybe you didn't put that line in?  As long as `set_poly_by_params` runs before your object tries to save or update you won't have the "venue" problem.

Comment: With 'venue', server gives error before rendering the form page to create a new item.

Comment: Alright I've updated the form to `form_tag`, `select_tag`, and `text_field_tag`.  This will not complain about any naming schemes in your form.

Comment: Here I am again. I was reading this tutorial http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/understanding-polymorphic-associations-in-rails and creating items like this commands "2.0.0-p247 :001 > ta = TeachingAssistant.create(name: 'ta_name')
2.0.0-p247 :002 > c = Course.create(name: 'course_name')
2.0.0-p247 :003 > ta.update_attribute(:ta_duty, c)" works. So i should try to write some code like this.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for people searching in 2023:

I was able to solve this issue for myself using the method discussed in this article: https://www.simplethread.com/building-a-polymorphic-select-dropdown-in-rails/ No Javascript needed.

As of Rails 4.2 you can call `to_global_id` on any record to get an ID that encodes the type and record ID. Some simple accessor methods let you retrieve and assign your polymorphic association via GlobalID.

Answer (score 0):

I used part of the solutions posted by 6ft Dan.

in items_controller i created a

```
before_action :set_activity, only: [:create, :update]
```

```
def set_activity
  @itemable = params["item"]["itemable"]

  if params["item"]["itemable"]["bar"]
    @activity = Bar.find(@itemable[3..-1])
  elsif params["item"]["itemable"]["res"]
    @activity = Restaurant.find(@itemable[3..-1])
  end
end
```

and then in create action i added

```
@item.update_attribute(:itemable, @activity)
```

after the

```
@item = Item.new(item_params)
```

and in my form i have

```
<%= f.select :itemable, options_for_select(@bars.map {|i| [i.name, "bar"+i.id.to_s]} + @restaurants.map {|i| [i.name, "res"+i.id.to_s]}) %>
```

Now item creates and has an itemable attribute linking to the activity which it belongs!

Comment: Polymorphic specifically uses `_id` and `_type` on the end of `itemable` to allow it's polymorphic design. The `itemable_id` is the reference to the foreign table `id` from which the `item` is now a child. `itemable_type` is like the species this child inherited.  For example, if I were to only have the `itemable_id` and not the `itemable_type`, then the child would **not** know which species it belonged to whether it's "Bar" or "Restaurant". When `itemable_id` is set to `3` and `itemable_type` is set to `Bar` then we know that this `item` is a polymorphic child of Bar, specifically of `id` 3.

Comment: One problem you may run into with your given example is you can have a **Bar** and **Restaurant** both with an ID of 14.  But you haven't told it whichever type it is in the **DB**.  So when you go to `.find(14)` which table are you going to use? **Bar** or **Restaurant**?

Comment: In the db table schema i have both #  itemable_id        :integer
#  itemable_type      :string(255) so I think it's ok. Will test a bar and a restaurant with the same id and i'll let you know if i will run into an error.

Comment: The point is the you don't know whether the user picked a bar or a restaurant from the form.

Comment: It works! Looking at the activeadmin item show page, in itemable_type i have the type of model 'Bar' or 'Restaurant' and in itemable i have the direct link to the bar or restaurant which the item belongs.